How to compare generalization errors of nested predictive models?
Suppose I want to compare two nested predictive models, for example a Lasso regression based predictive algorithm with and without a certain predictor Z. In the first predictive algorithm, Z would not be available in variable selection and in the second algorithm it would be available as a "new variable" and included in the model whenever useful.
To assess the usefulness of adding Z to the set of predictors, I report the generalization (aka out-of-sample) prediction errors of the two algorithms. Since the second algorithm (Z available) is just an extension of the first (Z not available), i.e. first algorithm is "nested" within the second, the generalization error of the second algorithm is necessarily less or equal to the first. For estimating the generalization error,  I use either of the two commonly used methods for this purpose: nested cross-validation (CV) or the optimism-adjusted bootstrap  method.
My question is this:
How should I decide if the second generalization error is actually smaller,
thus indicating the predictive potential of the new variable Z? In particular:

Can I calculate the standard error of the generalization error estimates based on the (left-out data in) the bootstrap samples or based on the held-out test sets in CV? In my view, it would make sense to calculate the difference of a performance metric between the 2 algorithms (for example RMSE) for each bootstrap left-out sample (or each test fold in CV), and then report the mean of these differences and its standard error.

Reporting standard errors would convince the reader that the observed difference is not attributable to random fluctuation due to too few bootstrap samples or cross-validation repeats. However, I think it would be wrong to have a test for the difference since by increasing the number of bootstrap samples (or CV repeats) I can always make the standard error arbitrarily small. I would like to report that the difference in RMSE between the 2 algorithms was 0.01 with say 95% confidence interval (0.007, 0.015). The reader is then convinced that I had enough repetitions and it then depends on the application how meaningful the observed difference is in practice . Do you think this makes sense?


In my opinion this is an essential issue in comparing nested predictive models and it seems to be often neglected. Typically the generalization errors are reported and compared without considering uncertainty in the estimates, which I find often inadequate. I assume it is often implicitly assumed that a large enough number repetitions has been applied. Anyway, one would still like to see an assessment of the uncertainty in generalization errors. But maybe I am wrong and this would often be considered too much information... Do you think this is the case and reporting standard errors for prediction errors is unnnecessary and why do you think this should be so?

Are you thinking in general or specific to a particular method like a LASSO regression or a neural network?

@Dave: Lasso regression was what mostly I had in my mind, because it would involve much less computational burden (in nested cross validation) than random forest or neural networks.

I think the assumption: "first algorithm is "nested" within the second, the generalization error of the second algorithm is necessarily less or equal to the first." is a bit wishful. $Z$ might introduce spurious correlations/overfitting that we are unable to account of it and then lead to higher generalization error. Yes, adequate regularisation should preclude that from happening, but it is a "should" not a "would". Anyway, that said, the Wilcoxon’s signed-rank test is probably your best bet, a simple, non-parametric test for pairwise statistical comparisons (say by repeated CV).

It can be disappointing when a post does not attract an answer, but making absolutely trivial edits to it to bump it up to the top of the list of recently active questions is not encouraged here. At least try to add some substance or improve clarity.
